# Custom BEP20 token and liquidity pool

Tags: liquidity-provider, decentralized-exchange

What does adding your custom token liquidity really do? Does adding your token to liquidity pool automatically get your token able to be listed or available for other coins?

Comment: Please don't use capitals. This means you're yelling and it is unecessary.